# Strange conditional probability proof

Tags: probability

I found in the following video that $P(B|A)P(A) = P(A \land B)$

But since $P(A\land B) = P(A)P(B)$,

that yields $P(B)=P(B|A)$.

I think I miss something here, could you please enlighten me?

https://youtu.be/9TDjifpGj-k?t=74

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P(A\cap B) = P(A)P(B)$ iff $A$ and $B$ are independent. That is a nontrivial property that does not hold for all pairs of events.

Also, this is very loosely related to the Bayes theorem, you should remove that tag.